# Most efficient way to split up a dataframe into smaller dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I am writing a python program that will parse a large dataframe (tens of thousands of lines) into smaller dataframes based on a column value, and it needs to be fairly efficient, because the user can change the ways they break up the dataframe, and I would like the output to update dynamically.

Example input:

| id | Column_1 | Column_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Oct | 10000$ |
| 1 | Dec | 9000$ |
| 2 | Oct | 3400$ |
| 3 | Dec | 20000$ |
| 2 | Nov | 9000$ |
| 1 | Nov | 15000$ |

Example Output:

| id | Column_1 | Column_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Oct | 10000$ |
| 1 | Nov | 15000$ |
| 1 | Dec | 9000$ |

| id | Column_1 | Column_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Oct | 3400$ |
| 2 | Nov | 9000$ |

| id | Column_1 | Column_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Dec | 20000$ |

The naïve way, in my mind, is to do something like this:

```
for id in list(df['id'].unique()):
    filtered_df = df[df['id'] == id]
```

But I believe this would be looping over the same data more times than is necessary, which is inefficient. Is there a fast way of doing this?

---

### Update

Did a little software drag racing. Here are the results:

```
%%timeit
[df.loc[df.id.eq(i)] for i in df.id.unique()]
```

9.96 ms ± 1.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
%%timeit
dflist=[]
dflist2=[]
for  k,v  in df.groupby(['id']):
    var='id'+str(k)
    dflist.append(var)
    globals()[var] = v
    dflist2.append(v)
```

1.28 ms ± 92.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

```
%%timeit
d = {id:df[df.id==id] for id in df.id.unique()}
```

9.19 ms ± 885 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Does anyone know why the second solution would be so much faster?

Comment: It would help to see some examples of what you mean by "the user can break the dataframe up by multiple values". In the xample you provided, the most efficient is likely to be `for g in df.groupby('id'):print(g[1])`. You could also look into [DataFrame.query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for more complex eval-based filtering

Comment: In the real example, the user can do things like change the dates they are looking at or filter by a specific day of the week, thus filtering the data down to a smaller or larger level. Either way, after any type of filtering on the data occurs, the dataframe needs to then be split by the 'ID' variable.

Comment: Worth linking: Pandas has really excellent [documentation on indexing, filtering, and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
# create lists to hold name and the trimmed data from df
dflist=[]
dflist2=[]
for  k,v  in df.groupby(['id']):
    var='id'+str(k)

# append dataframe name in a list
    dflist.append(var)

# create a DF with a variable name
    globals()[var] = v

# append dataframe in a list
    dflist2.append(v)
```

```
# to list all the dataframe created 
>>> dflist

['id1', 'id2', 'id3']
```

```
# accessing a dataframe
>>> id1


    id  Column_1    Column_2
0   1   Oct     10000$
1   1   Dec     9000$
5   1   Nov     15000$
```

```
>> dflist2

[   id Column_1 Column_2
 0   1     Oct    10000$
 1   1     Dec     9000$
 5   1     Nov    15000$,
    id Column_1 Column_2
 2   2     Oct     3400$
 4   2     Nov     9000$,
    id Column_1 Column_2
 3   3     Dec    20000$]
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
[df.loc[df.id.eq(i)] for i in df.id.unique()]
```

Output:

```
[
       id Column_1 Column_2
0   1      Oct   10000$
1   1      Dec    9000$
5   1      Nov   15000$,
       id Column_1 Column_2
2   2      Oct    3400$
4   2      Nov    9000$,
       id Column_1 Column_2
3   3      Dec   20000$
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary comprehension for that:

Input dataframe `df`:

```
d = {id:df[df.id==id] for id in df.id.unique()}
```

Use `d[1]` to get the (sub)dataframe for ID `1`.
Use `d[2]` to get the (sub)dataframe for ID `2`.
Use `d[3]` to get the (sub)dataframe for ID `3`.

```
d[2]
```

Result:

```
   id Column_1  Column_2
2   2      Oct      3400
4   2      Nov      9000
```